# Unit testing: How to test generic repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics, moq, mstest

I am trying to test my generic repository which looks like this

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly DbContext DbContext;
    public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public string Create(T item)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Id))
        {
            item.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        }
        item.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DbContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
        return item.Id;
        /*using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext())
        {
            item.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            item.CreatedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
            dbContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return item.Id;
        }*/
    }
    public T GetById(string id)
    {
        return GetFirst(x => x.Id == id);
    }      

    public T GetFirst(Expression<Func<T, bool>> @where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] nav)
    {
        return GetFiltered(nav).FirstOrDefault(where);
        /*using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            return GetFiltered(context, nav).FirstOrDefault(where);
        }*/
    }


    private IQueryable<T> GetFiltered(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] nav)
    {
        IQueryable<T> q = DbContext.Set<T>();
        return nav.Aggregate(q, (current, n) => current.Include(n));
    }

}
```

Based on the [microft's testing fundamental site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking) I tried to write few test cases.

Below is unit test code

```
[TestClass]
public class GenericRepositoryTest
{
    private Foo _foo;
    private IQueryable<Foo> _fooList;
    private Mock<DbSet<Foo>> _mockSet;  

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _foo = new Foo
        {            
            EmailId = "foo@bar.com",
            FirstName = "foo",
            LastName = "bar",               
            ProfileId = 27,
            IsDeleted = false,
        };  

        _fooList = new List<Foo>
        {
            new Foo{EmailId = "one@bar.com", FirstName = "one", LastName = "bar", ProfileId = 28, IsDeleted = false}, 
            new Foo{EmailId = "two@bar.com", FirstName = "two", LastName = "bar", ProfileId = 29, IsDeleted = false},    
        }.AsQueryable();
        _mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<Foo>>();
        _mockSet.As<IQueryable<Foo>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(_fooList.Provider);
        _mockSet.As<IQueryable<Foo>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(_fooList.Expression);
        _mockSet.As<IQueryable<Foo>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(_fooList.ElementType);
        _mockSet.As<IQueryable<Foo>>().Setup(m=>m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(_fooList.GetEnumerator());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Create_GivenEntity_ReturnsGuidId()
    {
        //Arrange
        var guidId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        var dbContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>().Object;

        IGenericRepository<Foo> genericRepository = new Mock<GenericRepository<Foo>>(dbContext).Object;

        //Act
        _waitingQueue.Id = guidId;
        var actualId = genericRepository.Create(_foo);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actualId);
        Assert.AreEqual(actualId, guidId);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetById_GivenEntityId_ReturnsEntity()
    {
        //Arrange
        var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        _foo.Id = id;

        var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
        mockContext.Setup(c => c.Foo).Returns(_mockSet.Object);
        IGenericRepository<Foo> genericRepository = new Mock<GenericRepository<Foo>>(mockContext.Object).Object;

        //Act
        var fooId = genericRepository.Create(_foo);
        var fooObject = genericRepository.GetById(id);

        //Assert
        fooObject.PropertiesShouldEqual(_foo);
    }
}
```

Here is DbContext

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("fakeConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Foo> WaitingQueues { get; set; }
}
```

I am new to unit testing and I don't know if the approach I am taking is the right one.

Currently, the first test `Create_GivenEntity_ReturnsGuidId` passes but the second test `GetById_GivenEntityId_ReturnsEntity` fails.

The error I get is on `GetFirst(Expression<Func<T, bool>> @where, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] nav)` method of GenericRepository

This is because the `GetFiltered(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] nav)` when called by `GetFirst` returns null.

Is it becuase at this point `T` is unknown for `GenericRepository<T>`?

Error I get is

```
System.ArgumentNullException
HResult=0x80004003
Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
```

When I debug I can see that `GetById(string id)` method has proper id passed into it

Can anyone suggest me what should I do? and what approach should I take?

Comment: Btw, in the test GetById_GivenEntityId_ReturnsEntity, you use the method Create from the repository but it is not declared in the code, can you add it ?

Comment: added method create

Comment: TO be honest.. you cant UNIT test a generic repository. You should Integration test it (using the Unit Test projects) Unit Testing - tests a unit of work that never changes. (1+1=2) If it generic there is no unit to test. Integration testing I did with Generic Repositories is to use an in memory database, write use cases, then write your tests (SpecFlow is great for this) - That way you are testing Use Cases always have the desired out come. If somebody changes an implementation (example OrderComplete) then the corresponding UseCase should fail if somebody made a mistake on a calculation.

Comment: As per your MIcrosoft Link.. Look `GetAllBlogsAsync_orders_by_name` is an extremely simple integration test. (using a mockset but it can be anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not setup DbContext.Set(), so, as Mock is on Loose Behavior by default, it should returns null.

The type of the set is not correct.

```
// should be Mock<DbSet<Foo>>
private Mock<DbSet<WaitingQueue>> _mockSet;
// what it MyDbContext ? should not it be DbContext ? has it is in 
// GenericRepository
var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();
// what is the point of this line ?
mockContext.Setup(c => c.WaitingQueues).Returns(_mockSet.Object);
// how to setup
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<Foo>()).Returns(_mockSet.Object);
```

nav is always null since you call GetFirst with only the predicate.

```
public T GetById(string id)
{
     // nav is null
     return GetFirst(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

Also, if you want to test the class GenericRepository, do not mock it in your tests, otherwise, what's the point to do unit tests on it ?

What you want to test is the logic behind and test if it can handle all inputs.

For ex, for the method GetById, test when id is null, id is empty, id does not refers to an existing entity and a successful test (entity found).

Comment: I understand what you mean. And thank you for the suggestion. As you mentioned i changed my code to `IGenericRepository<Foo> genericRepository = new GenericRepository<Foo>(mockContext.Object);` but still error still persists.

Comment: You mean it is not necessary to test if GetById method actually gets entity by id and we should just test how it handles if id is null or empty?

Comment: What I mean is what you should test are mostly unusual inputs and how your code handle it, but you need also to test how your code handle right inputs.

Comment: Exactly, in this case I want to test if given existing id the GetById method can get that entity. I hope CreateMethod actually creates the entity and is stored somewhere in the memory because it does not write in database. At least I am hoping its in memory object

Comment: Thing is I want to mention WaitingQueue as Foo for making question more easy to understand. I have setup DbSet. Please see the updated question

Comment: Since you use DbContext class and not MyDbContext and also, DbContext.Set<T>(), WaitingQueues is never called in your repository.

Comment: In microsoft's site they mention `var mockContext = new Mock<BloggingContext>();
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Blogs).Returns(mockSet.Object);` and not `var mockContext = new Mock<BloggingContext>();
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<Blogs>).Returns(mockSet.Object);` but like you set setup(c=> c.set<Blogs>) would work properly

Comment: I've been were you have been and doing it this way is a waste of time. What are you really testing? That the Generic Interface hasnt changed. Everything else is fuzz and meaningless. Create Use Cases, Write Integration Tests (Specflow) and Test journeys and outcomes. "Unit Testin" a database is testing if the database saved a record or not... (or that MockSets contain 2 records after adding 2 records??) pointless? I'm sure the tests in the Database make sure saving and reading works already before shipping  it. So really, not even testing the IGenericRepository at all.

Comment: What I was am trying to test is if the methods in the generic repository work as I expect them to. For exmple, create method actully creates an entity and returns id of the created entity, GetById method gets the entity given an existing id. Mocking DbContext i see that no entity are actully being saved in the database. So would this still be considered as integration test? I am just trying to test if my methods in generic repository behave as I expect them too

Comment: Well, ppumkin has a point, to test repository, you can do unit tests but it is better to write integration tests (with actual Db, not mock).

Comment: I was hoping once I test if Generic repository behaves as I expect it to then I don't have to test any other repositories that inherit generic repository. I am complete new to testing and still don't know where to set the borderline of what to unit test and what not to unit test

Comment: Unit test: you don't test the data but the logic, Integration Test: you test the data to check if everything is okay. Btw, I updated my answer, did you checked it ?